# Google Sheets regex keep part of text in each cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, extract, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a column with the following text in cells:

```
Colors/Red;Foods/Apple;Category/Featured;

Foods/Banana;Category/Recent;Colors/Yellow;

Colors/Blue;Foods/Grapes;Category/New;
```

I would like to keep only the `Category/Something;` text groups in each cell and remove all the other text.

For example I am trying to get the following:

```
Category/Featured;   

Category/Recent; 

Category/New;
```

I tried a regex like `/Category.*;$/g` (Start from `Category` end at first `;`) but it matched until the end of the text, not the semicolon `;`

I also tried `/Category.{1};$/g` but does not work.

Also I am not sure how to keep the matches and remove all the other text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "(Cat.*?\;)")))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",, SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(
 REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1:A, ";"), "^Category/.*"))),,999^99))), " ", ";")&";"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow that works great! Do you know if this would work to extract multiple matches as well? for example `Category/Featured;Color/Green;Category/New;` It looks like it extracts just 1

Comment: It looks like only in google spreadsheet, it extracts just 1 match. Otherwise the regex finds multiple matches if i try in a regex tester

Comment: Thank you! That was a very difficult formula for me! It works great now but there seems to an issue if there are spaces between words. For example `Category/Featured News;` will become  `Category/Featured;News;` The semicolon `;` is added in the space. I know I did not add those kind of examples in my question but is there a way to ignore the spaces? Spaces will be common.

Comment: @CyberJ sure, try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",, SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(
 REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, " ", "♦"), ";"), "^Category/.*"))),,999^99))), " ", ";")&";", "♦", " ")))`

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work. Am I supposed to add the diamond symbol too ♦ or is that something else being converted by stackoverflow?

Comment: Haha thanks! Just wanted to make sure as i haven't used it before. The formula works brilliantly.